# Rank and Kernel of subspace where dot product = 0.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

So if V ∈ R^n and  is the set of all vectors ∈ with the property that ⟨,⟩=0.
let ∈  be a fixed non-zero vector

we have a function   with domain    by  ()=⟨,⟩ ...(dot product)

**Whats the rank and dimension kernel of T?**
By rank I mean dimension of the Image/range of the codomain, and kernel is The vectors that go to zero, so that would be W.

I see it as T: R^n -> R

I thought the rank would be 0 because w vectors dot product to zero but this was wrong.
Any help in understanding would be great!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Its just a matrix-vector multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rank is $1$ since $T(cv)=c\|v\|^{2}$ so the range includes all points of $\mathbb R$. The dimension of the kernel is $n-1$ by the Rank Nullity Theorem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! That makes a lot of sense! I was confused thinking the domain was only the vectors in W so the Transform only outputed 0. Looking back what you said makes sense; and since the codomain is 1 then it can only be one! Then as you said with Rank Nullity... nullity = n-1! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The set $W$ is by definition the kernel of $T$, and the range is the whole real line since for any $c \in \mathbb R$ we have $$c = T\Big( \frac{c}{\langle v,v \rangle}v\Big).$$